# Flask ImportError: No Module Named Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm following the Flask tutorial here:

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

I get to the point where I try ./run.py and I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/Users/benjaminclayman/Desktop/microblog/app/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

This looks similar to:

[ImportError: No module named flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188240/importerror-no-module-named-flask)

But their solutions aren't helpful.  For reference, I *do* have a folder named flask which one user mentioned may cause issues.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi When I run Python and then import flask and check what version I have installed, it gives back "0.10.1".  So it looks like I have it installed...

Comment: You're saying if you run python and then do `import flask` you have no errors? Is it possible you have to versions of python on your computer?

Comment: Can you insert `import sys; print sys.path` in that file (before the line where the error happens) and also run that in the interactive prompt?

Comment: @ari I tried to do the virtual environment thing but may have messed it up somehow?  and yes, I'm using Python 3.3 but think I have 2.7 floating around

Comment: You aren't using version 3, you are using version 2, and you have two copies of Python version 2 on your mac, one that came with OSX, and the other that you installed. So, all in all - it looks like you have three versions of Python; Python3, Python2 (you installed), Python2 (came with the system). Sounds like you aren't using the correct environment here; where you have installed Flask is not the system default, and this is likely the cause of your headache.

Comment: This worked for me `python -m pip install flask`

Comment: It is common nowadays to use conda - so the command would be 'conda install flask'

Comment: rare but possible: make sure your python file is not named 'flask.py'

Comment: Check user permission as well

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Try deleting the virtualenv you created.  Then create a new virtualenv with:

```
virtualenv flask
```

Then:

```
cd flask
```

Now let's activate the virtualenv

```
source bin/activate
```

Now you should see `(flask)` on the left of the command line.

<sub>Edit: In windows there is no "source" that's a linux thing, instead execute the activate.bat file, here I do it using Powershell: PS C:\DEV\aProject> `& .\Flask\Scripts\activate`)</sub>

Let's install flask:

```
pip install flask
```

Then create a file named `hello.py` (NOTE: see `UPDATE Flask 1.0.2` below):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and run it with:

```
python hello.py
```

**UPDATE Flask 1.0.2**

With the new flask release there is no need to run the app from your script.  `hello.py` should look like this now:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

and run it with:

```
FLASK_APP=hello.py flask run
```

Make sure to be inside the folder where `hello.py` is when running the latest command.

*All the steps before the creation of the hello.py apply for this case as well*

Comment: You can place it anywhere as long as you run it with the virtualenv enabled.

Comment: Hi, I'm very new for python.  Everything just works fine with virtualenv in terminal. But, my problem is I'm using IDE Atom... can atom run the code at the same virtualenv environment?

Comment: I simply add to pip install flask in my environment.
Thank you Jeremy

Answer (score 87):

For python 3 use

> pip3 install flask

Comment: After changing my python version from 2.7 to 3, it worked!

Comment: Yes this works! Instead of doing pip install flask (which is for python 2), if you are using python3, you need to use pip3 install flask or other extensions of flask. To change your python version, you can use alias python="python3".

Comment: this is the answer that most people are probably looking for! Try this first if you are overwhelmed by the more complex answers

Answer (score 17):

After activating the virtual environment and installing Flask, I created an app.py file. I run it like this : `python -m flask run`. Hope this will help!

Comment: Not sure why this is working, probably something to do with the path.  Any insight on this?

Answer (score 15):

The only way I could solve was by adding my users python dir to myapp.wsgi file. As an example:

```
sys.path.append('/home/deployer/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
```

I guess that if you install the packages in the global enviroment, you should have no problem, but I had my python packages installed as user.

Comment: or by doing this `export PYTHONPATH=/root/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem with flasgger.

The reason for that was that I always use

`sudo pip install flask`

but for some reason that's not always the way to go.
Sometimes, you have to do just

`pip install flask`

Another gotcha is that sometimes people type `pip install Flask` with the **cap F**

Posting this here in case somebody gets stuck.
Let me know if it helped.

Useful Link:
[What is the difference between pip install and sudo pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068758/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-install-and-sudo-pip-install)

Answer (score 12):

This is what worked for me when I got a similar error in Windows:

1. Install virtualenv:

   ```
   pip install virtualenv
   ```
2. Create a virtualenv:

   ```
   virtualenv flask
   ```
3. Navigate to Scripts and activate the virtualenv:

   ```
   activate
   ```
4. Install Flask:

   ```
   python -m pip install flask
   ```
5. Check if flask is installed:

   ```
   python -m pip list
   ```

Answer (score 11):

Another thing - if you're using python3, make sure you are starting your server with `python3 server.py`, not `python server.py`

Comment: I upvoted this - such an common/easy mistake!

Answer (score 10):

this is what worked for me,

`sudo -H pip install flask`

Or for pip3(python3) use :

`sudo -H pip3 install flask`

*Sidenote*

If you're using virtualenv it's a good idea to 
`pip freeze >> requirements.txt` 
to allow for the installed packages to be listed in one place.
The `sudo` command and `-H` flag. For more on `sudo`'s `-H` flag, look at [Paul's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161711/paul-thompson) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28619739/7070685).
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

1. Edit
   `/etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp.conf`
2. Add the following two lines before the "WSGIScriptAlias" line:

`WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp python-home=/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/venv/FlaskApp`
`WSGIProcessGroup FlaskApp`

3. Restart Apache:`service apache2 restart`

I'm following the Flask tutorial too.And I met the same problem.I found this way to fix it.

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Answer (score 3):

I was using python2 but installed this:
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

Instead of:
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi

Correcting the installation solved the no flask problem.

Comment: Ah its the simple things. I had the wrong libapache mod wsgi in my dockerfile after upgrading to python 3... have a +1

Answer (score 3):

In my case the solution was as simple as starting up my virtual environment like so:

`$ venv/scripts/activate`

It turns out I am still fresh to Python :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Pycharm then this is the virtual environment issue.

So, at the time of creating your Python project you will have to select "Existing interpreter" option -> click "system Interpreter" -> select the correct option for example "*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3.6\python.exe".

You can use 'New Virtual Env' as well, but I have just given the quick fix that should work for Pycharm users.

Answer (score 2):

One stupid thing previous version seems to be using `Flask` while current is using `flask` make sure that you use flask with lowercase

Answer (score 1):

Go to the flask file in microblog, then activate the virtual environment with `source bin/activate`, then go to flask/bin and install flask, and the rest of the packages, `pip install flask`. You will see flask listed inside bin directory. Try to run `./run.py` again from microblog (or from wherever you have the file).

Answer (score 1):

Even i too suggest u virtualenv,
This might also solve ur problem.

```
sudo apt install python-flask
```

If u want to deploy in productionserver then go ahead with above solution else use virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer to this problem is specifying the correct path to flask in your environment. Make sure the script you are running knows how to get to the flask installation. Using print(sys.path) as mentioned above certainly helped to figure out the path(s) the script was using.

Answer (score 0):

enter your python interactive mode
then:

`import sys`

`sys.path`

it will print your path. Check wether flask is installed in the sys.path.

For MacOS, python path is under 
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

But pip'll install python package by default under
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

That's why it doesn't work for MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

The flask script is nice to start a local development server, but you would have to
restart it manually after each change to your code. That is not very nice and Flask can
do better. If you enable debug support the server will reload itself on code changes,
and it will also provide you with a helpful debugger if things go wrong.
To enable debug mode you can export the FLASK_DEBUG environment variable before
running the server:
forexample your file is hello.py

```
$ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
$ flask run
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case using Docker, my .env file was not copied, so the following env vars were not set:

.env.local:
`FLASK_APP=src/app.py`

so in my `Dockerfile` i had to include:

```
FROM deploy as dev
COPY env ./env
```

which was referenced in docker-compose.yml

`env_file: ./env/.env.local`

another thing i had to pay attention to is the path variable to ensure my environment is used

````
ENV PATH $CONDA_DIR/envs/:my_environment_name_from_yml_file:/bin:$CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH```
````

Answer (score 0):

my answer just for any users that use Visual Studio Flesk Web project :

Just Right Click on "Python Environment" and Click to "Add Environment"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using WSL and PyCharm / VSCode, the problem only occurred in the development environment and not in production. I realized that IDE's with WSL can have problems when exporting PYTHONPATH from their work directory and I started to do it manually.

Before running your program and inside a VENV, try running the following command:

```
export PYTHONPATH="path/my_user/code"
```

Comment: Hi... I am facing the same error. I have tried everything answered above, still getting same error. Could you please tell me how to do it manually. I am using VS Code. Python 3.9.5, flask 2.0.1

Comment: Hey bro! Try using the command in the edited comment, and tell me about success or failed

Answer (score 0):

In your case , the solution is  :

First:

Open the  terminal and navigate to the directory/folder where that python file is located ( in ur case the python file you created is run.py) and make sure you have installed flask in that same directory/folder.

Second :

Now , type the following command :

$python3   "pythonfilename" (in ur case, its $python3  "run.py")

[image: suuceessful]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error where it said flask module not found. this is what I did:

1. used venv to create a virtual environment $ python3.6 -m venv --without-pip virtual
2. activated the virtual environment using source virtual/bin/activate
3. downloaded pip into the virtual environment curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
4. installed flask using pip install flask

after running my application, all was good.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you first need to create a Python Environment

like this:

```
 py -m venv YOUR_DIR_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this workaround `set FLASK_DEBUG=1 && python -m flask run`
It worked for me

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me after upgrading pip:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Found that answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/3197202

Then I could just install flask:

```
pip install flask
```