# What is the difference between pip install and sudo pip install?

Tags: python, pip

I tried installing Flask and a few packages using sudo in a virtual environment, but on trying to import Flask, it'll throw up an ImportError. On installing the same packages with `pip install` though it works fine. 
So what's the difference between these methods? I tried this on Ubuntu.

Also, where does pip install these packages? Looking through Stack Overflow I could only find questions that answer how to list packages installed by pip, but not where to find them (in context to the virtual environment)

Comment: `pip install` installs as the user you are currently logged in as. `sudo pip install` installs as the root user

Comment: Usually the system packages are installed without write privileges for normal users so you must use `sudo` to elevate the privilege so `pip` can install to system packages. You can install a local copy of packages, ideally using `virtualenv`, where you wouldn't need elevated privileges.

Comment: Related: [Is it acceptable & safe to run pip install under sudo?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15028648/95735), [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/95735)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the risks of running 'sudo pip'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
pip install
```

Will run `pip install` as the current user

---

```
sudo pip install
```

Will run `pip install` with the **security privileges** of another user, `root` for example.
You normally need to use `sudo` to install a package on a system.

---

You may want to read [linux-101-introduction-to-sudo](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/linux-101-introduction-sudo/)