# Difference between sudo -H pip install and pip --user install

Tags: python, pip

I am wondering what is the difference between these two commands (I have the feeling that they are identical):

- `sudo -H pip install <package>`
- `pip --user install <package>`

**More informations:**
From the sudo manpage:

```
-H, --set-home
    Request that the security policy set the HOME environment
    variable to the home directory specified by the target user's
    password database entry. Depending on the policy, this may be
    the default behavior.
```

And the pip user guide: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/

**Related questions:**
[What is the difference between pip install and sudo pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068758/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-install-and-sudo-pip-install)
[What is the purpose of "pip install --user ..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user) and
[sudo pip install VS pip install --user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310688/sudo-pip-install-vs-pip-install-user)
But none of them talk about the `sudo -H` option or the precise difference between the two.

Comment: are identical if the user is root, the "--user" option install for current user only

Comment: duplicated of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-pip-install-user

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question has nothing about sudo in it.

Answer (score 0):

sudo is short for 'superuser do'. It simply runs the command with root privileges, which may be useful if you are installing to a directory you normally wouldn't have access to.

However, in the examples you have given the two commands would function identically, as you don't need root privileges to `pip install --user`

Comment: Could you explain why the: pip --version command returns me 18.1 and the sudo -H pip --version returns me 18.1 ?

Comment: `pip --version` does not require elevated permissions, therefore giving it those permissions with `sudo -H` will not change the output

Comment: It will not change ? But it actually does by me.

Comment: @s.k In your comment you said that both commands return 18.1. Was this a typo?

Comment: Oops, yes it was, sorry; pip alone returned 18.0. So I have to upload pip twice; one with sudo -H and one without.

Comment: @s.k This means that you have pip version 18.0 installed on your system, and pip version 18.1 installed in your home directory

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes down to the permissions that are given to the package, and the location where the package is installed. When you run a command as root, the package will be installed with root permissions.

Here's an example:

Running `sudo -H pip3 install coloredlogs` results in the following:

```
$ sudo pip3 show coloredlogs | grep Location
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages

$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
drwxr-sr-x 4 root staff 4096 Feb 25 01:14 coloredlogs

$ which coloredlogs
/usr/local/bin/coloredlogs
```

Running `pip3 install --user <package>` results in the following:

```
$ pip3 show coloredlogs | grep Location
Location: /home/josh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

$ ls -l /home/josh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
drwxrwxr-x 4 josh josh 4096 Feb 25 01:14 coloredlogs

$ which coloredlogs
coloredlogs not found
```

Notice the location differences between the two, and also notice that the package isn't installed on PATH when installed using the `--user` flag. If for some reason I wanted to directly call the package, I would need to add `/home/josh/.local/bin` to my PATH.