# where should pygame be installed by pip? /usr/lib or ~/.local/lib?

Tags: python, pip, pygame, carla

I was testing CARLA, a self-driving car simulator on ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS last year and at that time, I had installed pygame. At that time pygame had been installed under /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame and I had fixed a file there to make it work right.
Now, recently I re-installed ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS for the machine (only the OS part) and tried testing CARLA and found I have to install pygame(which is of course). So I did `pip install pygame`(without sudo) and CARLA now works again.
But soon I found the location of pygame installation is now not /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame but  ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame.
Why is it installed in my local home directory, not in the system directory? (I tried installing it with sudo, but it says Requirement alread satisfied.)
I tried `python -m pip uninstall pip` but received message below.

```
 Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 19.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

should I do `pip upgrade`?
ADD : This question is not about 'sudo' or 'apt install'. Normally in `apt install`, if we omit `sudo`, it asks for root priviledge and doesn't install it. But pip installs it under ~/.local. Therefore this question is different from suggested duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between pip install and sudo pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068758/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-install-and-sudo-pip-install)

Comment: Did this or my answer clarify your original question?

Comment: @hyperTrashPanda  yes, thanks! (I was busy after selecting your choice and checking it's correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `python -m pip uninstall pip` is meant to uninstall pip, not `pygame`, so you *wouldn't* want to do that.

When invoked with `sudo`, pip will install the libraries system-wide on `/usr/lib`, so they're accessible by all users.

When called *without sudo* and/or with a `--user` flag, they're installed for your user only on your home directory. In either case, `pip` reports the library as already installed, and doesn't need to re-install it. Take a look at the link provided by triplee, as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412974/how-to-uninstall-a-package-installed-with-pip-install-user)

You can use the following, to verify that Python looks at both of these paths to find available libraries.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

To address your point, *both of these locations are fine*, it just a matter of preference.

If you want to uninstall `pygame` from `~/.local` you should try `pip uninstall pygame`, and then use `sudo pip install pygame` again, to have a system-wide, static version installation.

In my opinion, it's better to have user dependencies gathered locally, so that each user is free to install/remove/update libraries and modules to his requirements, and preferably inside his [Virtual Environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Comment: Hi, Thanks!. Correct. I didn't know for pip, if we omit 'sudo' it installs under ~/.local. Usually, when we use install using `apt install`, it asks for root priviledge and doesn't install, which is different from pip behavior. That's what I was not aware of.

Comment: Glad your question was answered!

Comment: now I uninstalled pygame in ~/.local and then I installed it with `sudo` and it's now installed in /usr/local.