# Configuring Apache to server fails with Error 500. error.log says "ImportError: No module named flask"

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

**SSH to a VPS running ubuntu and installed flask, Apache, and WSGI with the following:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install --user Flask

sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

**cloned git repo that had the hello.py program with the following code:**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

**created hello.wsgi file in VPS by running the following:**

```
nano hello.wsgi

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/firstapp")
from hello import app as application
```

**created apache configuration pointing to above .wsgi by running the following in VPS:**

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
nano hello.conf

<VirtualHost *>

ServerName example.com

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/firstapp/hello.wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess hello
<Directory /var/www/firstapp>
WSGIProcessGroup hello
WSGIApplicatioinGroup %{GLOBAL}
Order deny,allow
Allow from all

</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Configured Apache to serve Flask application by doing the following in VPS:**

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo a2ensite hello.conf
sudo servive apache2 reload
```

**if I go to the VPS public IP the application fails with Error 500, when i run "sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log" I get the error "from flask import Flask ImportError:No module named flask**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask ImportError: No Module Named Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252791/flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of linked issue. The answer already given is spot on in  that issue was because OP installed packages to per user site-packages directory. The linked issue was due to different reasons. Do not close this as duplicate as will loose the correct answer for this variation.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install --user` installs your packages into a user-specific directory that Apache doesn't know about. I would recommend you [use a virtualenv](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html) but you can still use your user's site-packages if you can find its path:

```
python -c 'import site; print(site.USER_BASE)'
```

Then you configure mod_wsgi to use the path:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess hello python-home=/path/to/your/env
```

Although it is recommended that you use a virtual environment and not a per user `site-packages` directory, if you really must use the per user `site-packages` directory, use something like:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess hello python-path=/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: Using a virtual environment works. however finding the path and configuring mod_wsgi still left me with the same error

Comment: @pinkraindancer: Did you install the packages within the virtual environment?