# ImportError: No module named 'flask'

Tags: python, flask, importerror

I am trying to build a new API in my already well running system. and suddenly my page stopped responding with Internal server Error.

When i checked the Apache logs i had the following error

```
[client 166.137.143.124:40797] mod_wsgi (pid=4153): Target WSGI script '/var/www/barnyard/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://162.243.13.216/display
[client 166.137.143.124:40797] mod_wsgi (pid=4153): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/barnyard/flaskapp.wsgi'., referer: http://162.243.13.216/display
[client 166.137.143.124:40797] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://162.243.13.216/display
[client 166.137.143.124:40797]   File "/var/www/barnyard/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://162.243.13.216/display
[client 166.137.143.124:40797]     from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: http://162.243.13.216/display
[client 166.137.143.124:40797]   File "/var/www/barnyard/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>, referer: http://162.243.13.216/display
[client 166.137.143.124:40797]     from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, url_for, redirect,session,jsonify, g, referer: http://162.243.13.216/display
[client 166.137.143.124:40797] ImportError: No module named 'flask', referer: http://162.243.13.216/display
```

This is what happens when i try to install Flask again just in case it wasn't installed correctly.

```
root@PHost1:/var/www/barnyard/FlaskApp# sudo pip install flask
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask) (2.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask) (0.11.15)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask) (6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.21 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask) (0.23)
root@PHost1:/var/www/barnyard/FlaskApp#
```

And then i try to see if it wasn't installed in the virtualenv

```
root@PHost1:/var/www/barnyard/FlaskApp# source venv/bin/activate
(venv) root@PHost1:/var/www/barnyard/FlaskApp# pip install flask
Requirement already satisfied: flask in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask) (6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->flask) (1.0)
(venv) root@PHost1:/var/www/barnyard/FlaskApp#
```

After checking everything seems fine but still the error exists.

*Python version*

```
root@PHost1:/var/www/barnyard/FlaskApp# python -V
Python 2.7.12
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, It does. "Flask==0.12" This was there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252791/flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask

This helped me look into the error of installing a wrong library but i dont understand how it worked until now if the library was wrong

Comment: Have you by any chance named any file `flask.py`?

Comment: When I get import issues I add this code just before line which caused an error. `import sys, os; print(sys.version); print(sys.executable); print(os.environ["PATH"]); print(os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]); print(os.getcwd())`. It shows what interpreter app uses and where it searches libraries. With that information it's quite easy to understand what went wrong.