# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Tags: python, flask

After reading title of this post, don't try to make duplicate first because herewith content may be asked in different way. Btw, I'm very new in python and start learning now for work requirement.

here are my dependencies

`virtualenv --version => 15.0.2`

`pip --version => 19.0.3`

`flask --version =>  1.0.2, Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 17 2018, 19:45:58)`

`python --version => 3.7.1`

And, here is my source code of `main.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

Problem is following error encountered when I render like `python main.py`

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from flask import Flask ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

But when I render like `FLASK_APP=main.py flask run`, it was working. Please let me know how's difference between `python ...` and `FLASH_APP= ...`

Comment: It seems that you have nstalled flask that uses Python 2.7 version, but your default python is Python 3.7.1. Are you showing package versions from your virtualenv, or are some of these packages globally installed?

Comment: @bagljas it's install inside virtualenv

Comment: Can you please check output of following commands in the terminal in which you had `flask run` command working and `python ` not?  `which python`, `which pip`, and `which flask`. They should all show paths to executables in your virtualenv e.g. `~/.virtualenvs/tmp-ec6bfce85be4e9c8/bin/python`

Comment: Furthermore, for you app to work via command `python main.py`, you should add ` if \_\_name\_\_ == '\_\_main\_\_': \n   app.run()`

Comment: Will `pip uninstall flask && python -m pip install flask` do the trick?

Comment: @bagljas both are under my project directory `/Users/user/Documents/Projects/Python/flask/bin/...`

Comment: @PavelVergeev that was working. Cool...

Comment: @PPShein awesome! That means that probably command `pip` points to the wrong, system-wide, `pip`. In order to use the local pip do `python -m pip`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`pip` can for some reason point to system-wide `pip` (which on many systems corresponds to Python 2.7). In order to use `pip` from the virtualenv, use `python -m pip` command. The following command will do the trick:

```
pip uninstall flask && python -m pip install flask
```

Another possibility is that you installed flask via `apt` and not `pip`. Here's the difference between the two: [What is the difference between `sudo apt install python3-flask` and `pip3 install Flask`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453599/what-is-the-difference-between-sudo-apt-install-python3-flask-and-pip3-instal)

So now the `flask` command is available system-wide.

If this is the case, uninstalling flask with `apt` and installing it with `pip` should do the trick:

```
sudo apt remove python-flask
pip install flask
```

(this is my guess that the `apt` package is called `python-flask`.

Comment: Funciono para mi.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are fine but you may need to be careful of the version of python you use to install `flask` this time. For me,

```
pip3 uninstall flask && python -m pip install flask
```

did not work, but

```
pip3 uninstall flask && python3 -m pip install flask
```

did work. The issue of having the right version when installing flask and its installation in the virtual environment also has consequences. Find out more in this article: [ModuleNotFoundError](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-flask).

Answer (score 0):

As Pavel said; you might use python 2.7 instead of python 3 to run your project...

I had this issue and by using this command instead of Pavel's command, problem fixed

```
pip uninstall flask && python3.7 -m pip install flask
```

> You can replace *flask* by any other lib and this will work

Hope it works for everyone sees this too

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio Code IDE with pipenv and getting the above error, you should check this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355059/getting-error-no-module-named-flask-in-vscode-even-when-i-have-installed-flas)