# ModuleNotFoundError although package is installed

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I amd getting:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'**, when trying to run a file that starts

> from flask import Flask

- i am using PyCharm on Ubuntu VM.
  Opened the terminal under venv directory. this is what i am getting:

> ```
> ~/PycharmProjects/project01/venv$ python -m flask --versionFlask 1.0.2
> Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
> [GCC 7.3.0]
> ```

why does my interpreter can't find the flask module (i am guessing this is not specific to flask)? tried to browse through some previous suggested solution like this: [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55116381/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-flask)
but it didn't solve the problem
Made sure my PyCharm project interpreter is pointing to **/home/my_user/PycharmProjects/project01/venv/bin/python** and not another interpreter
The only way i could have solved it is by installing the flask through the PyCharm Gui, but i really would like to understand why installing from the terminal with `pip install flask` didn't work

Answer (score 0):

`source venv/bin/activate`

And install `flask` on the venv; after run the script using the venv python binary. - I believe you either have not installed `flask` in the virtual environment or you're not using the virtual environment python.

To check which python binary you're invoking:

`whereis python`

Comment: yes, that did the trick! i guess flask was not installed on that environment.  so what does it mean the output that i am getting when i ask from the terminal **python -m flask --versionFlask** where does it prints the version of flask from?

Comment: Your `/usr/bin/python` - you can use `whereis python` to see which python binary you're using. - If it helps and answers your question, mark it as your answer.