# 'No module named flask' in VSCode even when I have installed flask

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have my Flask installed in my main directory for playing with Flask projects and I don't want to change it (its name is tryFlask).
My project is in one of the subdirectories to tryFlask (main_project).
How should I config my launch.json so that it doesn't throw errors when I try to debug?

Current config which throws:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "my_app.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "tryFlask",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

And yes I have already checked `"FLASK_APP": "my_project/my_app.py"`. Doesn't work. Neither does reinstalling dependencies or even choosing different interpreters from venv's `bin` subdirectory.

Comment: No matter where you installed flask, just choose the interpreter for the python environment where flask is installed.

Comment: Yes I chose it from the venv's bin directory, @JialeDu, but I have shortcuts to interpreters. I even swapped them. Still throws error

Comment: Can you show how you choose? Provide more details.

Comment: cmd + shift + P (I'm working on Mac) -> Python: Select Interpreter -> Choose path -> Find -> tryFlask -> bin -> shortcut to Python3 or Python3.10;

Neither works, @JialeDu.

I also tried my main Python 3.10 that was in suggested interpreters

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use flask with vscode, following this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask) is a good start.

According to the question in your post, if you want to specify the python interpreter when debugging, you can add the `python` configuration to **launch.json**

*Simple example:*

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            // Modify the python interpreter with flask installed on your machine
            "python": "C:\\WorkSpace\\pytest10\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe"
            // "python": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/Scripts/python.exe"

        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

For more **launch.json** configuration, you can check this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_set-configuration-options).

Comment: You should use `${workspaceFolder}`, ideally

Comment: Could you provide more detail about where and which key to put?
Preferably an article / tutorial where you have found this answer, @JialeDu

Comment: I updated the answer, feel free to let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I used my main Python path on MacOS: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3" And I got: SyntaxError: invalid syntax on this very line of code, @JialeDu. And yes I strated with this tutorial, but couldn't get the app to run in the VSCode terminal so skipped this part - choosing different interpreters, neither worked. I don't have Scripts directory in my venv and still Flask is working well.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have a mac to reproduce your problem. One other suggestion is to use the code in the picture in my answer to get the full `path` to the current interpreter, then `path -m pip install flask` install flask.

Comment: Thank you, @JialeDu. I use flask only for some projects and I don't think that I want to install it globally.
I will now use the built-in debugger and create non-training projects with venv directory inside each project separately.
If this doesn't work I think I will create another thread in which I will specify the OS from the beggining

Comment: OK, sorry I wasn't helpful. If you find a solution, you can come back and write it down and let us know.