# Problem with the execution of script using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have created a python script inside the virtualenv and tried to execute that file. This is my code:

```
(env) C:\Users\amitayadav\Documents\Amita_projects\Python\flask_project>python3 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

It throws an error. However, when I run this command it runs fine:

```
(env) C:\Users\amitayadav\Documents\Amita_projects\Python\flask_project>python app.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 500-586-454
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I don't understand why this is happening. What is the problem with the python3 command?

Comment: because flask is installed for python (python2 ) not for python3. 

install pip3("sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip"), and install flask using "sudo pip3 install flask" and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages are installed only for the Python version that the virtual environment is configured to use, which is generally just run as `python`.

When the virtual environment is created, the interpreter is copied for use within that environment. By running the `python3` interpreter, you might end up with an interpreter outside your environment, that doesn't have the required dependencies installed.

If you want to have the virtual environment use the Python 3 version, you might need to create the virtualenv with the optional `--python` flag to indicate that:

```
virtualenv --python=python3 my_virtual_env_directory
```

Then you just again install the required packages as before:

```
pip install flask
```

Then you just run as usual:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 29 2018, 11:42:59) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask
>>>
```

The correct versions of `pip` and the interpreter `python` are used implicitly to install dependencies and to run your application.

Answer (score 0):

Your global packages does not have `flask` library installed. the code that is executing successfully is being run inside a virtual environment which has the flask dependency installed.

Run the command `pip install flask` outside the virtual environment and it should start the flask application.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install flask?

```
pip install flask
```

[Also check this answer, it may help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47114637/11187717)

Comment: But I have installed flask by this command `pip3 install flask flask-sqlalchemy`