# Pylint error: no name in module when import a package

Tags: python, flask, pylint

I'm learning a little bit how function python, more specific Flask.

I'm creating a new project using `flask`, but when I create a new file and `import Flask` I receive this error: `No name 'Flask' in module 'flask'pylint(no-name-in-module)`

I did read that, I need create a file called: `__init__.py` but I have this and the error keeps showing up.

This is my actual code (very simple code, and `folder/files` structure):
[image]

Thanks for the help! :D

I tried this: [Flask ImportError: No Module Named Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252791/flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask), but this solution does not works for me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This means, flask is not inslled in pycharm project's virtual env .

Comment: but... i did install Flask using "pip install flask" into my Virtual env

Comment: well, you need to configure your python interpreter in the VS code. once configured your Virtual environment and install flask in that virtual env your ide error will gone

Comment: then may be python interpreter is not installed in visual studio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask ImportError: No Module Named Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252791/flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask)

Comment: @TOH19 i did Try to do this, but not works for me.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani i did uptate the post with the captures about my vs config

Comment: hi, please see the post updates. i did add my vsCode config

Comment: u need to add the interpreter to the project in VS code, not use terminal  output, u r using default python environment not the virtuaal one

Comment: I selected the python interpreter like this: (ctrl + shift + p) > Python: select interpreter > (in this step Vs code show me two options, one is the env the other is python global). i did try selecting the two options but the error appear whit both

Answer (score 0):

I installed `flask` on `python 2.7` and run simple hello world script and it worked fine. Then I updated `python` to `python 3.8` and I got an error similar to yours:

```
Unable to import 'flask'pylint(import-error)
```

I simply uninstalled `flask` and installed again and it worked for me. Run this two commands:

```
pip uninstall flask
pip install flask
```

Then export the `FLASK_APP` environment variable and run `flask`

```
set FLASK_APP=file.py
flask run
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this changing my python interpreter. I did uninstall `pylint` and install `pylama` and now all is fine!