# I am new to flask tryin to run first application .. here is my code and what turns back in terminal .. any suggestions?

Tags: flask

> code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request

from flask_session import Session


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False

app.config["SESSION_TYPE"]= "filesystem"

Session(app)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if session.get("comments") is None:
        session["comments"] = []

if request.method == "POST":
    comment = request.form.get("comment")
    session["comments"].append(comment)
```

> CMD

(env) E:\COURSES\CS50W\lec2\exersice>set FLASK_APP=application.py

(env) E:\COURSES\CS50W\lec2\exersice>python -m flask run

E:\COURSES\CS50W\lec2\exersice\env\Scripts\python.exe: No module named flask

Comment: you need to install flask, `pip install Flask` on your cmd, `Flask` is not installed. Simple googling would give you the answer

Comment: flask is already installed

Comment: It most probably is. Google the problem and I'm sure you'll find answers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252791/flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask
go to this question

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252791/flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask) out.
If you are not sure whether you have installed flask or not, try running only `flask` in the cmd or any terminal.If you get any commands about flask then you can be sure that it is installed or you can install by using

```
pip install flask
```

If you are concerned about the versions of the libraries you use for your application, then follow the above mentioned link!