# from flask import flask module source not found

Tags: python, flask, discord.py

Im trying to import flask and I already have it installed by doing `pip install flask` but im getting the error, `Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\colee\Downloads\Ultimate-Bot (3)\keep_alive.py", line 1, in <module> from flask import Flask ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'` Also when I hover over the error, it says `(module) flask Import "flask" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource` I looked in my site packages for Python39 and flask is there. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252791/flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask ImportError: No Module Named Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252791/flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use uppercase Flask