# No module named 'flask' despite package being isntalled?

Tags: windows, pycharm

I was previously using Thonny as my IDE which was good. But I wanted GitHub integration so I decided to switch to PyCharm.

I created a virtual environment for the project inside of the project directory and installed all of the packages including Flask, Flask-WTF, Flask-Login, PyMongo, etc.

When I run the file I get 'No module named 'flask''

I am not sure what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to **virtualenv** by your OS-specific command and then install **flask** and its *modules*.

For more info: [Flask ImportError: No Module Named Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252791/flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask)