Unable to deploy a flask application with distroless container image
I am trying to deploy my web-application
with docker container. My Dockerfile contains
# base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# working directory
WORKDIR /test

# moving files into working directory
COPY . /test


# install the dependecies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

# run app 
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]

it is running fine, but when I am trying to run via distroless image, it is not working. Not getting the issue.
################################
# First stage: build environment
################################

FROM ubuntu:20.04 AS builder

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /test

# Copy all files to the working directory
COPY . /test

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt

##########################################################
# Second stage: runtime environment using distroless image
##########################################################

FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian10

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /test

# Copy the necessary files from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /test /test

# Run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]

not getting where the problem lies. When I am running with docker build -t img . and docker run -d -p 5000:5000 <ID> , it's not showing any error, but when I am doing docker ps , it is showing empty list.
Here is what it shows in the pip install -r requirements.txt step.
Collecting Flask
  Downloading flask-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
Collecting gunicorn
  Downloading gunicorn-22.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
Collecting requests
  Downloading requests-2.32.3-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Collecting click>=8.1.3
  Downloading click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting importlib-metadata>=3.6.0; python_version < "3.10"
  Downloading importlib_metadata-7.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting Jinja2>=3.1.2
  Downloading jinja2-3.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting Werkzeug>=3.0.0
  Downloading werkzeug-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous>=2.1.2
  Downloading itsdangerous-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting blinker>=1.6.2
  Downloading blinker-1.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (9.5 kB)
Collecting packaging
  Downloading packaging-24.1-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2
  Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (141 kB)
Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Downloading idna-3.7-py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Downloading certifi-2024.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (164 kB)
Collecting zipp>=0.5
  Downloading zipp-3.19.2-py3-none-any.whl (9.0 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.5-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (26 kB)
Installing collected packages: click, zipp, importlib-metadata, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, Werkzeug, itsdangerous, blinker, Flask, packaging, gunicorn, charset-normalizer, urllib3, idna, certifi, requests
Successfully installed Flask-3.0.3 Jinja2-3.1.4 MarkupSafe-2.1.5 Werkzeug-3.0.3 blinker-1.8.2 certifi-2024.6.2 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 click-8.1.7 gunicorn-22.0.0 idna-3.7 importlib-metadata-7.1.0 itsdangerous-2.2.0 packaging-24.1 requests-2.32.3 urllib3-2.2.1 zipp-3.19.2
Removing intermediate container 03c1d3384625
 ---> 86bd0b241cc3

I tried searching but the issue remains same. This is what I am getting every time.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-95:~/Newz_Shortie$ sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 ec0ffa7cc27d
6cdef3bb508fca725f42a459144c563a10577a66231aae4a21c148ae19fa6b5e
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-95:~/Newz_Shortie$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-95:~/Newz_Shortie$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND            CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
6cdef3bb508f   ec0ffa7cc27d   "python3 app.py"   34 seconds ago   Exited (1) 33 seconds ago             cranky_euclid
0081643a01e6   hello-world    "/hello"           14 minutes ago   Exited (0) 14 minutes ago             festive_einstein
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-95:~/Newz_Shortie$ sudo docker logs 6cdef3bb508f 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request, redirect
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

I tried removing the entrypoint and only running the CMD ["app.py"] but nothing worked. Wondering where I am mistaking. I tried the solutions of Stackoverflow too.

You should be able to get the logs by doing docker ps -a (this also shows stopped containers) followed by docker logs <container name>.

@HansKilian Okay. It's showing the module flask is not getting installed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 1, in 
from flask import Flask, render_template, sonify, request, redirect
II tried the solutions mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252791/flask-importerror-no-module-named-flask but nothing improved.

Can you show us (by editing your question, not by adding it as a comment) the output of the pip install -r requirements.txt step?

@larsks sure. I added it.

I'm no Python expert, but it seems that pip installs packages under /usr/local/lib/pythonX.XX/site-packages (where X.XX is the python version number), so you need to copy that over too. I don't know if that's the only place it installs stuff to, so I don't know if it'll be enough.

@HansKilian yes it started working when I restarted my container added the script from the official https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless . Thanks :) . It was for my blog and now it's published. Yay!

You're not copying over the Python libraries (flask) which are installed to a different directory.
One option is to use a venv to bundle everything up and copy that over. This example is taken from a guide using the Chainguard distroless Python image, but should be very similar for Google distroless images:
FROM cgr.dev/chainguard/python:latest-dev as builder

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PATH="/inky/venv/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /inky

RUN python -m venv /inky/venv
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

FROM cgr.dev/chainguard/python:latest

WORKDIR /inky

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PATH="/venv/bin:$PATH"

COPY inky.py inky.png ./
COPY --from=builder /inky/venv /venv

ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "/inky/inky.py" ]

