# pip install ansible directory owner error

Tags: python-2.7, pip, ansible

When trying to `sudo pip install ansible` on mac OS 10.12 I get the error:

> The directory '/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its
>   parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has
>   been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that
>   directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>
> The directory '/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent
>   directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been
>   disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If
>   executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

I checked the owner of the current and listed directories using `ls -l` and they are all the same. (The first `ls` is the parent directory of `website` where I am trying to run the install)

```
My-Mac:Artivest myuser$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   9 myuser  staff   306 Jul 23 11:12 developer_tools
drwxr-xr-x   2 myuser  staff    68 Jul 23 11:32 modules
drwxr-xr-x   3 myuser  staff   102 Jul 23 11:29 virtualbox-images
drwxr-xr-x  54 myuser  staff  1836 Jul 23 11:48 website
My-Mac:Artivest myuser$ cd /Users/myuser/Library/Caches/pip
My-Mac:pip myuser$ ls -l
total 8
drwx------  8 myuser  staff  272 Jul 23 12:20 http
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser  staff  113 Jul 23 11:00 selfcheck.json
My-Mac:pip myuser$ cd /Users/myuser/Library/Caches/pip/http
My-Mac:http myuser$ ls -l
total 0
drwx------  3 myuser  staff  102 Jul 23 12:20 1
drwx------  3 myuser  staff  102 Jul 23 11:00 9
drwx------  5 myuser  staff  170 Jul 23 12:20 a
drwx------  3 myuser  staff  102 Jul 23 11:00 b
drwx------  3 myuser  staff  102 Jul 23 12:20 e
drwx------  3 myuser  staff  102 Jul 23 11:00 f
My-Mac:http myuser$
```

How can I get past this error?

Comment: Neither of the directories you listed is owned by the current user, which is `root` for the command you ran.

Comment: Why is it root? when I run whoami I get myuser?

Comment: Find a difference between `whoami` and `sudo pip install ansible`.

Comment: I also tried `pip install ansible` to no effect

Comment: I'm not suggesting. That's a fact.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install: Please check the permissions and owner of that directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870003/pip-install-please-check-the-permissions-and-owner-of-that-directory)

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest installing python using [brew](https://brew.sh/), then you could try:

```
$ pip install --upgrade --user ansible
```

This will install ansible within your `$HOME` if using python 3 it will be in `/Library/Python/3.7/bin` or if using python 2 in `~/Library/Python/2.7/bin`