# Changing ownership of libraries installed on python virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, unix

I created a python virtual environment using root user and installed 9 python libraries on the virtual environment using the same user. The root access has been revoked now and am unable to access libraries using my own userid (that is not root).

How can we change the permission of the libraries so that my userid can access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the issue by changing UNIX file permissions pack to your user. Try:

```
$ sudo chown -R USERNAME /Users/USERNAME/Library/Logs/pip
$ sudo chown -R USERNAME /Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/pip
```

then pip should be able to write those files again.

--[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871374/16139621)

Comment: Thank you ! But what if 4-5 users want to use the same package? Do we have to changing the permission to every user in that group?

Comment: The chgrp command changes the group ownership of a file. The basic syntax is as follows − $ chgrp group filelist

Comment: You can read more on that in this website https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm

Answer (score 1):

The only user that is allowed to change the ownership or permissions of a file that they do not themselves own is the superuser (regular users can "super user do" using `sudo`, of course, but this is an exception that must be granted by the root user). In other words, you need someone with root access to change the ownership or access permissions.

Comment: Thank you ! Let me ask the person with root access to change the permissions. Our team has 4-5 users. How can we assign permission so that the entire team, not just my userid, can access the packages?